# How to search among comments?

Tags: support, comment, search

I remember someone mentioned about the meaning of "order" in first order language and second order language in a comment to one of my questions. But I searched with "first order" with my id "user:1281", it doesn't find the post I am looking for.

I also remember I had the same problem when search for some comments before.

So did I search in the correct way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think the built-in search supports searching in comments. You can use Google instead: "[site:math.stackexchange.com first order tim](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com+first+order+tim)" finds what I think is [the comment you are looking for](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/125672/856#comment290133_125672).

Answer (score 3):

I've composed the [SEDE query *Search comment by keyword AND Q/A author*](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1337211/search-comment-by-keyword-and-q-a-author?keyword=first%20order&PostAuthor=1281) to address your question.  My query has two input fields:

1. `keyword`: the keyword search you want.  In your question, it's `first order`.  I've chosen a [very insensitive collation](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1337214/utf8-collations), but feel free to adjust it to your needs.
2. `PostAuthor`: the question/answer's author.  In your question, it's `1281`.

It displays the desired links, comment score and the creation dates.

[image]

Comment: I will add that some some queries for searching comments can also be found in other posts on this meta, such as: [How to browse or search comments?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12142) or [How can I search my comments with keywords?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20297) And also on [meta.se]: [Can I search my comments using some keyword(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148066) or [Ability to search comments would be useful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183142).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for sharing this useful list of common queries.  I will consult your comment in the future in case that I need to perform standard queries.  In this question, there're two particular restrictions that aren't present in your linked queries: search "parent post author ID" (Q/A's author's user ID) AND comment keyword.  Apart from that, the classic SQL criteria for filtering comments `WHERE UPPER(Comments.Text) LIKE UPPER('%##CommentText##%')` is less efficient than an SQL collation.

Comment: So I guess this would be a bit closer: [How to search for a comment left by a particular user on my post?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9460) Certainly, some of the other queries do not use collation (and some of them are case sensitive).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Nice found.  Actually mine is forked from his, but that's standard code that I believe almost everyone (of my generation) on math.SE can write if they want to, since the syntax of SQL is declarative: one just describe the criteria to be satisfied, and let the SQL database manager to do the query optimisation on server side.