# How can I search my comments with keywords?

Tags: support, comment, search

> How can I search my comments with keywords in them?

Comment: Older posts: [How to browse or search comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12142/how-to-browse-or-search-comments) and [How to search among comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3917/how-to-search-among-comments)

Comment: @MartinSleziak First link doesn't concern searching for specific keywords. 2nd link seems to suggest only Google can help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [this Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/76958/search-your-comments) with your UserId (found in the URL of your profile page). The search is not case-sensitive.

Usage example: [your comments with the word "hint"](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/76958/search-your-comments?Pattern=hint&UserID=107671).

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that data in SEDE are updated [once a week](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq). So the most recent comment will not be found this way.