# Adding a reference/citation to someone else's post

Tags: discussion, editing, citation

Is it encouraged to add references/citations to someone else's post (when you are absolutely sure about it)?

Comment: It isn't wrong to do so.  I generally offer the link or citation in a Comment for the post's author.  Rarely I introduce an inline link to the post itself.  This is often by way of introducing some background definitions to a Question that makes it accessible to a wider audience.  It's possible that I've never unilaterally done so for an Answer.

Comment: I  think the most respectful approach is to suggest the reference/citation in a comment, encouraging the asker/answerer to include  it.

Comment: You may add a source, but please read the entire post you duplicated, @DatBoi

Comment: Maybe you should clarify whether you are talking about questions, answers or both. (Since I see that a post which was suggested as a duplicate deals, as far as I can tell, mainly with questions.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I wish that this be addressed(for both questions and answers) separately in this thread. I don't think the tiny point mentioned in the post linked offers a very useful insight.

Comment: This seems related to this Q I asked: [If I recognize the source of someone's question, should I edit to add it?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33402/) At the moment, my stance is that I do it when I feel *absolutely* certain, especially if the OP has not been around for a while. But others seem to prefer to "[ask for permission rather than forgiveness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/it%27s_better_to_ask_forgiveness_than_permission)".

Comment: @CalvinKhor your post is exactly what I was looking for! Reading all the comments, the community indeed prefers leaving the source as a comment.

Comment: If the OP is newish as well I hope it shows them the ropes. Related point - I think it should be more acceptable to replace broken links, or links that might break soon, cf [Domains with dead links](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34712/). Yet I do agree that there is somehow more ownership in answers

Comment: @CalvinKhor Speaking of links, does including the source in the post itself, rather than in comments affect the search visibility?

Comment: While I believe it is possible to search in comments, perhaps via SEDE, searching using math.se's own search bar does not. You can try for instance `url:"https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/it%27s_better_to_ask_forgiveness_than_permission"` which appears in my above comment, but there are [no results](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=&q=url%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fen.wiktionary.org%2Fwiki%2Fit%2527s_better_to_ask_forgiveness_than_permission%22&mixed=0). Similarly if you e.g. give a full (non-hyperlink) citation in the comments. There's probably an improvement to google search results.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Exactly as you said, to search in comments one can use SEDE: [How to browse or search comments?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12142) and [How to search among comments?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3917) (Of course, Google crawler might pick up things both from comments and from answers - so searching using Google can find comments, too.)